# Finding the point and function of a parabola

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

Let's say I have the parametric function$$f(t)=5\text i+\cos t\text j+(1+\sin t)\text k$$Where $t$ ranges from $-\frac \pi2$ to some number, say $a$. I want to be able to connect $f(t)$ with another function $g(t)$ that takes the form of a parabola
$$g(t)=5\text i+t\text j+\frac 4{25}t(50-t)\text k$$ such that the piecewise function$$F(t)=\begin{cases}f(t)\qquad-\frac \pi2\leq t\leq a\\\\g(t)\qquad a\leq t\leq\infty\end{cases}$$
is both continuous and differentiable at $t=a$. How do I go about finding the $a$ value?

---

I tried finding the curvature of both equations to set them equal to each other. The curvature of $f(t)$ is simply one while the curvature of $g(t)$ is$$K_{g(t)}=\frac {5000}{\left[64(t-25)^2+625\right]^{3/2}}$$However, there is no value of $t$ according to Wolfram Alpha that has the curvature of $g(t)$ equal to one. Is there any way for me to actually solve for $a$ and $g(t)$?

Comment: You do not need the curvatures to coincide if all you need is differentiability. You need to impose continuity first and see if there is any solution for your a. You only have one parameter, so it may be impossible to achieve differentiability. Your problem is too "rigid".

Comment: @GReyes Hm, alright then. Let's assume I have the two functions$$f(x)=\begin{cases}t\cos t\,\text i+t\sin t\,\text j+(t+6\pi)\text k\qquad-6\pi\leq t\leq 0\\\\t\,\text i+(-0.4t^2+6\pi)\text k\qquad\qquad 0< t\leq 5\end{cases}$$How do I position the parabola so that $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable?

Comment: @GReyes Currently, the two functions both meet at $(0, 0, 6\pi)$ when $t = 0$. But how do I make both differentiable? Do I just differentiate $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ functions and set them equal to each other? This seems like such a straightforward problem, yet I can't figure it out. >:(

Comment: Your combined curve is continuous, since the two pieces agree at $t=0$ as you mention. To be differentiable, you need a common tangent at $t=0$, that is, you need to take the derivative of the first piece at zero and see if it is equal to the derivative of the second piece at zero. When you do that, you get the vectors $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ which do not match. A way to solve it is adding $t$ to the $z$-component of your parabola, that is, setting $(-0,4t^2+t+6\pi)$ in front of $k$. Then you get a differentiable curve. But I do not know if that is what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by “connect?” There is no value of $t$ for which the two functions in your question coincide. The parabola and circle do intersect, so you could reparameterize one of them to create your piecewise function, but the tangents at the two intersection points don’t match.